# ReactJS Question Component function scope and sharing functions

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a question about ReactJS and components, specifically about how functions interact within the component system.

In this example:

```
// Index.js

import React from ‘/reactʼ;
import ReactDOM from ‘/react-domʼ;
import App from ‘./App.jsʼ;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById(‘rootʼ));


// App.js

import React from ‘/reactʼ;

class App extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {someProp = ‘ʼ}; 
    };

    functionA = (e) => { console.log(e);
    };

    Render() {
        return <div><ComponentA /></div>
    }; 
};

export default App;

// ComponentA.js

import React from ‘/reactʼ; 
import App from ‘./../App.jsʼ;

class ComponentA extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {someProp = ‘ʼ}; 
    };
    functionB = App.functionA

    Render() { 
        return(
            <div>
                <input onSubmit={this.functionB} />
            </div> 
        );
   }; 
};

export default ComponentA;
```

ComponentA imports App.js and attempts to assign App.functionA to functionB and then call it in the JSX. This results in a failure basically saying that the function is not defined.

I know this is NOT the way to function share (I have learned about passing functions through props etc).

I simply just want to know WHY this does not work, to help me better understand the mechanics of React, and Javascript in general.

Thank you,
Curtis

Comment: You should research redux, then functionA is a action in reducer.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function from another React component, you can write static methods in ES6 notation. If you are using ES7, then you can also write static properties.

You can write statics inside ES6+ classes this way:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
...
}

static someMethod(){
}
```

}

[Working Demo about static function](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-static-function)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm kind of noobish so can you explain why a non static function does not work? Like I said I just want to understand the mechanic of this. Is it because the function doesn't exist until the class is initialized or something?

Answer (score 0):

My noob brain finally figured it out lol... I think.

Basically because an instance of the class [the App component] was not initialized within the scope of ComponentA, the App function is not accessible.

This made it work (DISCLAIMER: I DO NOT PLAN ON DOING THIS, I KNOW ITS TERRIBLE CODE)

```
// ComponentA.js

import React from ‘/reactʼ; 
import App from ‘./../App.jsʼ;

class ComponentA extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {someProp = ‘ʼ};
        this.appInstance = new App();
    }
    functionB = (e) => {
        this.appInstance.functionA(e);
    }

    Render() { 
        return(
            <div>
                <input onSubmit={this.functionB} />
            </div> 
        );
   } 
};

export default ComponentA;
```